# Time complexity for nested loops

Tags: time-complexity

Here is a nested for loop. I work out the time complexity for it is nlg(n).

```
 int sum = 0;
 for(int k = 1; k < n; k*=2){
     for(int i = 1; i < n; i++){
            sum++;
     }
 }
```

My thoughts are as follows.

1. The outer for loop: `k` will take values of 1, 2, 4, 8, ... Thus it will take lg(n) iteration.
2. The inner for loop: `i` will take n iteration.

Hence, the overall operations taken will be nlg(n).

Am I right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the order of growth you suggested is correct. You can show it like the following:

[image]